# Kafka producer too slow

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am trying to store request response logs in my Kafka queue, over spark framework.

Dependencies I use:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Code:

```
private static void startKafkaProducer() {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", _properties.getProperty("broker.request"));
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeSerializer");
        props.put("acks", "0");
        props.put("retries", 0);
        props.put("batch.size", 1);
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", false);

        _producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n>>>>>>>>\nstartKafkaProducer()\n>>>>>>>>\n\n");
    }

    public static void routeToKafka(String incomingrequest, String optionalEsId, String topic) {
        try {
            System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n>>>>>>>>\nrouteToKafka()\n>>>>>>>>\n\n");
            System.out.println("Request: " + incomingrequest);
            System.out.println("topic: " + topic);
            _producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic, incomingrequest));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

My usecase limits me to send only one message across at a time -- That is as soon as my server receives a request I process it and compute a response, which hardly takes 1ms and then I queue this into Kafka, which to my amazement takes 6000ms or greater each time.

I am using similar code in my other project albeit the key and value serializers / deserializers and works much faster there.

Here is how I try to add records, this is a plain JSON string.

```
routeToKafka(dataset.toJSON().toString(), null, PREDICT_TOPIC);
```

Am I missing something here, as adding to queue blocks my HTTP request response, whilst I am willing to start a separate thread for the above call but the latency seems to be huge.

Comment: You mean the `_producer.send` is slow? Have you tried debutting it to see where all this time is spent?

Comment: I doubt similarly to @M.Prokhorov. It may not be that `_producer.send` is taking up time. It may be something else. You should debug this with time metrics per function.

Comment: When I add `props.put("max.block.ms", 0);` everything seems fine and the control is returned immediately. However I would need more help of how to `debutt` the producer?

Comment: `props.put("batch.size", 1);` seems quite suspicious: A small batch size will make batching less common and may reduce throughput (a batch size of zero will disable batching entirely). A very large batch size may use memory a bit more wastefully as we will always allocate a buffer of the specified batch size in anticipation of additional records.

At the end of the day it make the `send()` method blocking (by default this method is non-blocking).

Comment: I mistook the interpretation there, I was looking for realtime. I will check with increasing the batchsize.